# Want to remove port number from https URL

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, deployment

I want to remove port number from URL. I have installed apache server and tomcat both on ubuntu. And created SSL certificate on a domain name. So it's fully secure connection.

Below is my URL.
https://DomainName:8443/AppName. 
The application is running fine with above URL.

I am expecting URL -  https://DomainName/AppName

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the port in your Tomcat server.xml, from 8443 to 443. Unless you're using Apache as a reverse-proxy, in this case you have to configure it with an SSL virtual host.

Comment: While the "true" answer is "change the port number", changing the port number isn't always [straightforward](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_to_run_Tomcat_without_root_privileges.3F).

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz In wide environments we have load-balancers in front of Tomcats, and maybe several Tomcats hosted on the same servers, on different ports. This is one proof that Tomcat is successful, despite its documentation is sometimes old, too vague, or not going to change even after noticing the mailing list that something is wrong and getting an answer such as "we know but we don't change that and by the way, we don't thank you".

Comment: I've been a member of the Tomcat community for 15 years. If there is a problem with the documentation, we do indeed fix it. The real problem is that these things are complicated, and most people are looking for quick-fixes.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz can u provide some useful links for SSL virtual host with Apache2. It will be helpful.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I know that you answered to thousands questions on the user mailing list, and I was there too sometimes, and that Tomcat team is more opened to suggestions than most of projects. But very often, arrogance and frustration are met in the "open" source community.

Comment: @EugèneAdell The problem is that there are [33 current committers](http://tomcat.apache.org/whoweare.html) (most of whom aren't currently active) and several million users worldwide who constantly register complaints of one kind or another. Patches are always welcome. Suggestions are also welcome. Bad manners generally gets you a negative response. We are all volunteers. I'd be happy to continue this conversation over on the Tomcat users' list.